# iPhone CSS - Viewport width not working for me

Tags: iphone, css, mobile

Anyone know why I still have some extra white space to the right of my web site when using an iPhone?:

(please check on an iPhone - this will not show with Firefox/UA Switcher)

I've adjusted viewport meta to "device-width" and my body's width is 100%.

I've Firebugged everywhere and just can't figure this one out.

Comment: I think it comes from your CSS. 

But if you don't give us a clue (like some css codes), it'll be difficult to help you ^^

Comment: vinzius - what kind of info do you need, b/c I think posting the entire CSS is going to be too long - can you see the CSS via Firebug on Firefox with UA Switcher?

Answer (score 0):

You must set the width with "device-width" like this :

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width;" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to wrap all your page content in `DIV` with just `overflow:hidden` style (no more styles necessary).